# question how to increase game speed

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i'm building a simple flash game that shows up little spheres (different in size, x and y). Users has to click on them to remove them.
the more seconds pass by, the faster the spheres have to show up. 
if you have to many spheres on the screen, you lose. So if you are a very fast and accurate clicker, you get much further then if you are slow. 
my question now is: how can I manage the speed of the spheres showing up?
I'm using a timer now, that times every 2 seconds. So in the beginning we need to go slow, the more seconds have passed the more spheres show up. Or the more spheres you've clicked away, the faster the games goes.

any ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call the timer you can set the timer's delay property just a bit lower.  You can control how fast it speeds up by how you modify the time.  Example:

```
function OnTimer(e:TimerEvent):{
     //This will check to see if we are between the 10th and 20th time that this timer has been called.
     if(myTimer.currentCount > 10 && myTimer.currentCount < 20){
          //We will speed up the timer by 100 milliseconds, or .1 seconds.
          myTimer.delay -= 100;
     }
     //Spawn a new circle in the game
     SpawnCircle();
}
```

This example will cause the timer to delay for 2 seconds the first 10 times.  Between the 10th and 20th times, it will speed up by .1 seconds each time.  After the 20th time it will retain it's speed, which will be 1 second at this point.

Answer (score 0):

each time the timer goes of just decrease the the delay time of the timer. Use a counter for nummer of spheres clicked away and decrease say 2000 by that number.

```
var numSpheresClicked:int;

var timer = new Timer( 2000, 1 );
timer.addEventListener( Timer.TIMER, createSphere );


function createSphere( evt:Event ) {
     addSpheretoStage();
     timer.delay = 2000 - numSpheresClicked;
     timer.reset();
     timer.start();
}
```